# Swiper Slider get jumped when scrolling through the touchpad (Used nested Slider)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, slider, swiper.js

Here is the url: https://manageprojectsdemo.com/test2/

The code I'm using

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
```

var swiper = new Swiper(".mySwiper", {
spaceBetween: 0,
loop: true,
speed: 1000,
autoplay: {
delay: 4000,
disableOnInteraction: false,
},
pagination: {
el: ".swiper-pagination",
clickable: true,
},
navigation: {
nextEl: ".left98",
prevEl: ".right98",
},
});
var swiper2 = new Swiper(".mySwiper2", {
direction: "vertical",
slidesPerView: 1,
loop: false,
speed: 1000,
mousewheel: true,
longSwipes: false,
continuousVertical: false,
scrollOverflowOptions: null,
threshold: 1,
shortSwipes: true,
spaceBetween: 0,
pagination: {
el: ".swiper-pagination",
clickable: true,
},
});
});